# Remove an empty script in wordpress header

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress, wordpress-theming

My WordPress version is 3.2.1.

An empty script is placed inside the head tags:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='Actual theme path?ver=3.2.1'></script>
```

I deactivated all my plugins and checked it. But it looks that same. Then I looked into my `functions.php`. I can see the following scripts:

```
wp_enqueue_script('nivo', BFI_TEMPLATEURL . 'scripts/jquery.nivo.slider.js', array('jquery'),'3.2.1');
wp_enqueue_script('bfi', BFI_TEMPLATEURL . 'scripts/bfi.min.js', array('jquery', 'superfish', 'cufonfont', 'ytchromeless', 'flowplayer', 'ajaxupload', 'nivo'), '1.0.14');
```

The empty script that I mentioned comes between these two scripts but I couldn't find it in `functions.php`.

Comment: Have you looked in header.php itself?

Comment: Yeah. It is from wp_head(); function

Comment: `Actual theme path` - is it quote from source of the generated page? Or do you mean 'real path to your theme' by that? I haven't understood.

Comment: @Ruslan Polutsygan It is real path to my theme.

Comment: So whole code is something like this <script type='text/javascript' src='http://google.com/wp-content/themes/my_best_theme/?ver=3.2.1'></script> And without pointing to any js-file. Correct?

Comment: @Ruslan Polutsygan absolutely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is `jquery.nivo.slider.js`-file included? I'm asking because '3.2.1'-version of this script required and in the 'empty script tag' version equals to '3.2.1' too `Actual theme path?ver=3.2.1`. 
If you answered 'no' to the previus question,
Is jQuery library script included? It could be the reason because according to this

```
wp_enqueue_script('nivo', BFI_TEMPLATEURL . 'scripts/jquery.nivo.slider.js', array('jquery'),'3.2.1');
```

nivo slider script depends on jquery script.

Also,
Have you opened header.php-file of your theme? Maybe you have this string hardcoded in this file. It is improbable, but may be...

Comment: At last i found that empty script and removed it. Your suggestion helps me to find the bottom of it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Deactivated or deleted? Because if you deactivate the plugin, the script files are still in the root js directory of wordpress.

Comment: I actually deactivated. Do you want me to delete it? Please let me know. Thanks

Comment: If you don't want to use those plugins, delete them and see if that fixes the problem.